Should we gitignore `Package.realitycomposerpro/WorkspaceData` for Reality Composer Pro projects?
Should we add Package.realitycomposerpro/WorkspaceData/* to .gitignore for Reality Composer Pro projects?
I see files with my computer name and other JSON files in here that are highly updated by just by opening and closing files in Reality Composer Pro.

I don't know if you should ignore the whole folder, but I just ignored the *.rcuserdata file. I added this to .gitignore: **/*.rcuserdata And ran git rm --cached <file> to stop tracking the file.
